# RowCause (Specified value is reserved and cannot be used): [RowCause]

Tags: sharing, owd, userrecordaccess, sharerecord, field-integrity-exception

My requirement is when user submit the log it should make the log record read only for the user who is submitting it and representative(another field on log which has lookup with user ).

**I have kept OWD private. And there is modifyall access on the profiles.**

what I have done in my code is, I simply querying relevant share record and making access to Read. PFB code

Correspondence_Log__Share corrShare = [SELECT Id, ParentId, UserOrGroupId, AccessLevel FROM Correspondence_Log__Share WHERE parentId =: corrData.Id];

corrShare.AccessLevel = 'read';
update corrShare;

**But it is not working, it gives me an error :
first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: RowCause (Specified value is reserved and cannot be used): [RowCause]**

It will be great if someone can help me. I have tried many options but not able to find any solution.
if Somebody has any other approach  to fullfill my requirement then it will be awesome.